# filtering object HTMLSpanElement and add className to that object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dynatree

This code alerting 1. object HTMLLIElement 2. object HTMLSpanElement.

I only want to filter all object HTMLSpanElement and append className+='parent1'

```
var htmlLabelElementObj = HtmlDocObj.getElementById(CurrentNodeId);
var current = htmlLabelElementObj.parentElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
while (current.parentNode){
     current = current.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
     alert(current);
}
```

This below code is static. I am doing like this in a dynamic way.

```
htmlLabelElementObj.parentElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.className+=' parent1';
htmlLabelElementObj.parentElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.className+=' parent1';
htmlLabelElementObj.parentElement.parentElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.className+=' parent1';
```

This above code is setting the className by adding to current node. parentNode.parentNode.firstChild every node.

**EDIT:**
i tried find and filter but it not working.

```
if($('current').find('[object HTMLSpanElement]'))
{
    alert(current);
}

if($('current').filter('[object HTMLSpanElement]'))
{
    alert(current);
}
```

Comment: can you share the related html also

Comment: i edited for more clearance. not able to share html because i am working on live. this code is fetching jquery dynatree parent nodes and changing the folder icon by appending className

Comment: i edited static code which works fine. tested i only wanted to do in a dynamic way. every current node i want to add parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.className+='parent1'

Comment: Html like <ul> <li> <span/> </li>  <li> <span/> </li> </ul> now can you help me @Arun P Johny

Comment: Maybe you should read the jquery docs first, as your usage of jquery is not quite correct.

Comment: I go through the examples on w3school. .find() is perfect for me in this situation but didn't working. i debugged also. In that examples there are html tags in that you want to find. here i want all [object HTMLSpanElement] from loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution to my own question. dynamic getting all node with span filteration

```
var testspan='';
var current = htmlLabelElementObj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
   while (current.parentNode){
 //this current variable add every time two parentNode to reach li of parent
        current = current.parentNode.parentNode; 
        if(current != null)
        {
             // this code to reach span of li and change the span icon of parent class
            testspan = current.firstChild;
            if(testspan == '[object HTMLSpanElement]' && testspan.className != ' parent1')
            testspan= testspan.className+=' parent1';   
        }
        else
        {
            break; // this is for preventing an exception of childnode
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help someone. like i suffered for making static code to dynamic.